# Looping through pandas dataframe using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to loop through a pandas dataframe and for every row add a new column called `upper`, whose value should be set according to a simple condition based on the values of two other columns of the same row.

I tried to do that using list comprehension:

```
df['upper'] = [df['Close'][i] if df['Close'][i] > df['Open'][i] else df['Open'][i] for i in df]
```

But this line of code gives me the following error:

```
raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: 'Date'
```

Where `Date` is just another column of the dataframe that isn't even involved in that line of code. What am i doing wrong here? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the content of the variable `i` the string `'Date'` by any chance? Since you're looping `in df` it should return the column names, that's where you get the error from.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*pandas* is an advanced library, looping over *DataFrame* is a bad practice

```
df['upper'] = df[['Close', 'Open']].max(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
df['upper'] = np.maximum(df['Close'], df['Open'])
```

Comment: No need to import numpy for that

Comment: Besides, it show poor understanding of pandas slicing mechanism

Comment: Quality answers typically include an explanation as to why/how your code addresses the OP's issue, and includes caveats.